# Java - Enable combobox

Tags: java, swing, combobox, radio-button, jradiobutton

My code looks like this:

```
public class ReservationsWindow extends JFrame {

        private JLabel lblDriver;
        private JComboBox cbDriver;

        private JComboBox cbDispathcer;
        private JLabel lblDispatcher;

        private JLabel lblVehicle;
        private JComboBox cbVehicle;

        private JRadioButton rbMobileApp;
        private JRadioButton rbTelephoneCall;
        private ButtonGroup bgOrder;

        private JLabel lblNote;
        private JTextField txtNote;

        private JButton btnAplly;

        private void initActions() {
            rbMobileApp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    rbMobileApp.addItemListener(evt -> {
                        cbDriver.setEnabled(evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
                        txtNote.setEnabled(evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
                    });
                }
            });
            rbTelephoneCall.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    rbTelephoneCall.addItemListener(evt -> {
                        cbDispatcher.setEnabled(evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
                    });
                }
            });
```

I want to enable combobox depending on which radiobutton is checked. But, when window is open for the first time all Comboboxs are enabled, then I have to click on one of them (and it's still everything is enabled), and only then when I click again on other radiobutton everything works fine. I want to everything works fine on first click. How to fix that?
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you disabled combo boxes first time? I can't see that code. And also you need to disable other combo boxes which are not related to radio button in radio button action listener code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, for better help sooner please post a proper [mcve]